# Взаимосвязь SslClient с lsass.exe

Tags: c#

Дело в том что в софте используется некоторые классы из `System.Security.Cryptography` и `SslClient`, который в нескольких потоках подключается через TLS к другим серверам. При этом служба `lsass.exe` дает серьезную нагрузку на процессор, если софт не работает - `lsass.exe` не отжирает ресурсы процессора.

Есть ли взаимосвязь `SslClient` либо `System.Security.Cryptography` с `lsass.exe` (Local Security Authority Subsystem Service)? Так же в чем может быть причина такой загруженности службы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsass.exe` - это хост-процесс для стандартных Security Protocol Providers. Первоначальная установка TLS-соединения (рукопожатие, хэндшейк, обмен ключами) происходит именно в нем. Т.к. для HTTPS установка соединения - это относительно ресурсоемкий процесс - вы получаете high cpu при большом количестве одновременно открываемых соединений.